# C# Find object in List<T>

Tags: c#, list, find, exists

I have a List. I want to know how to write LINQ or so to find if their exists an obj of MyTypes whose id = "CLR".

I would like to know if it exists and its index. So if it exists, then thru its index I can replace with a new object of MyTypes else add it.

I know I cna do it thru iterating the items in List, but that will be time consuming than using LINQ statement. Correct me if am wrong.

Can any provide help.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do.  Can you show the iteration method you currently know of to do this?  That code might clarify the overall intent.

Comment: Is this on List<T> or List<MyTypes>. Also Linq will not be faster than iterating through the list, just more generic and more usually more succinct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't really need LINQ for this; there's the handy [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
int index = foos.FindIndex(foo => foo != null && foo.Id == "CLR");

if(index != -1)
{
     Foo replacement = ...
     foos[index] = replacement;
}
else
{
     Foo toAdd = ...
     foos.Add(toAdd);
}
```

By the way, are you sure you don't actually need a lookup-table of some sort? Your usage pattern suggests  you wan't a `Dictionary<string, Foo>` or similar rather than a list.

Comment: Thanks Ani. Actually I have 2 master objs MySaw & MyType. Both may contain 4-5 records. And For each MySaw their can be all/few MyType. So for each Saw, I was thinking of an obj SawTypeCollection with MySaw and List<MyTypes>. Finally for the collection of all saw's & types, I opted Dictionary<String, List<MyTypes>> the String is the id of MySaw & List is List<MyTypes> from SawTypeColelction. So, u guys feel the SawTypeCollection should have Dictionary<Saw, MyTypes> rather than having List<MyTypes> ??? I am getting lost in this to some extend.

Comment: Sounds like `List<MyType>` should be `Dictionary<string, MyType>` instead. Hard to say without more info though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you intend to iterate though the entire collection at some point it might make more sense to use a Dictionary instead.  Doing so will allow you to locate an item by key, check if an item is present by key, and insert by key.  Not only that, but these type of operations are quicker on a dictionary since its essentially a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
MyType item = MyList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == "CLR");

if (item != null)
{
    int index = MyList.IndexOf(item);
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Why check for its presence and *then* find the index? Why not just find the index, and check whether the return value is -1? (See Ani's answer.)

Comment: Yep, I was thinking that, but I went with `FirstOrDefault` cause the OP was asking for a LINQ example. Of course, Ani's answer is more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is something like

```
var obj = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == "CLR");
if(obj != null)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```